# Add and Remove items between List Boxes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am trying to achieve manage and exchange "items" between two list boxes that are located on my UserForm. I.E. I have items in ListBox1 (I use multi-select), then click the "Add" command button and all the items are added to ListBox2. - that piece of code works. I can also remove items from ListBox2 based on the selection or a "Clear All" command button.

When I add similar code used by the "Remove" command button to the "Add" command button I get an error. My goal in this is to remove items from ListBox1 so that I do not re-add or duplicate them again in ListBox2. The error is "Run-time error'- 2147467259(80004005)': Unspecified error".

I have narrowed the problem down to a source but I do not know how to solve it. The problem is the way I populate ListBox1. Currently, I populate ListBox1 using a named range, this named range refers to a column in a table.

> ```
> MyUserForm.ListBox1.RowSource = "ListOfItems"
> ```

If I use the following code, I do not get the same error and everything works fine.

> ```
> With MyUserForm.ListBox1.
>    .AddItem "Item 1"
>    .AddItem "Item 2"
>    .AddItem "Item 3"
>    .AddItem "Item 4"
> End With
> ```

I would really like to stick to the first "method" of populating ListBox1, as the named range is dynamic and due to change frequently.

Here is the code that works. I usethis code to "Add" items to ListBox2 (I have numbered the code lines for easy reference):

> ```
> (1)For i = 0 To LIstBox1.ListCount - 1
> (2)   If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
> (3)       ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)
> (4)    End If
> (5)Next
> ```

And here is the code I use to remove the items from LitBox1 that has already been added to ListBox2:

> ```
> (6)For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
> (7)    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
> (8)        ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
> (9)        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
> (10)    End If
> (11)Next
> ```

The above-mentioned error is on line (9) when I click debug. I have tried the code with and without line 8, but no luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for the looking post, I thought it is better to give more details than way too little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set the RowSource property for ListBox1, instead add items by looping through the range ListOfItems during the UserForm initialize event like this...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cell As Range
With Me.ListBox1
    For Each cell In Range("ListOfItems")
        .AddItem cell
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

And then underneath the commandbutton (named AddItem in the sample code) to add the selected items to the ListBox2, place the following code...

```
Private Sub AddItem_Click()
Dim i As Long
With Me.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem .List(i)
        End If
    Next i
    For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            .RemoveItem i
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to populate your listbox by looping over the named range.  I think that could leave it dynamic but add things one at a time.

```
For each entry in sheet1.range("ListOfItems") 'adjust sheet as necessary
    MyUserForm.ListBox1.AddItem entry
next
```

Comment: Thank you Sobigen and sktneer. The solutions you proposed works perfectly! I assumed that "entry" should be declared as a range.